# Wordpress - eCommerce cat/attribute nav

Tags: wordpress, navigation, e-commerce, wp-list-categories, jigoshop

I am currently looking in to setting up a new Wordpress site using Jigoshop as an ecommerce solution. The site will only have 1 product say `bikes` but will have various types/sizes of bikes.

Now I'm trying to determined the best structure for this. I was thinking of making each 'bike'  is own product. Having various categories for each type - 'Street', 'Mountain', 'Cross' etc and setting the size of the bikes via a product 'attribute'. This all sounds ok to me but there maybe a better way to sort products into those groups, feel free to explain if there is a better way.

Now where I'm getting stuck is I want to have a sidebar menu that lists following.

1. Street

   - small
   - Medium
   - Large
   - X-Large
   - etc
2. Mountain

   - small
   - Medium
   - Large
   - X-Large
   - etc
3. Cross

   - small
   - Medium
   - Large
   - X-Large
   - etc

But I can't think of a way to list all the categories and then by size attribute. Can anyone help me with how id go about breaking the menu down like this?

really appreciate any input.

---

Ok so I'm still struggling with this, I've tried the following code but its not quite.

```
$pos_tax = 'pa_tyre-position';
$terms = get_terms( $pos_tax, '' );
if ($terms) {
foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo '<p>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($term, $pos_tax)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a></p> ';
    echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'pa_size', '<li>', ',</li><li>', '</li>' );

}
}
```

Can anyone help me fix this? Its listing out terms the don't belong to the top taxonomy

Comment: Ok so I've come across the (Layered nav) widget and this is almost what I require. Can someone help me out on how I could combined both (Product Cat) widget and (Layered nav) widget so I'd get similar to what I've outline above?

Comment: Ok well I'm still struggling with this.